Can not able to display after array.push(....)
<template>

<div class="overlay_CompareItem"></div>
<div class="modal_CompareItem">
    <header class="modal__header_CompareItem">
        <h2>Compare Computers</h2>
        <button @click=(closeModal) class="close-button_CompareItem">&times;</button>
    </header>
    <main class="modal__main_CompareItem">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Brand
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr :key="index" v-for="(compareThis, index) in list_of_computers">
                    <td>{{compareThis.brand}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </main>
</div>

<script>

import axios from "axios";
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            list_of_computers: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchComputer(1)
        this.fetchComputer(2)
    },
    methods: {
        async fetchComputer(productId) {

            const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5030/api/Products/CompareProducts/' + productId);
            const finalRes = await res.json();
            
            this.list_of_computers.push(finalRes);

            alert(JSON.stringify(this.list_of_computers));  // LINE #1

        },

        closeModal() {
            this.$emit('close');
        },

    }
}

Notes:
The above LINE #1 generates the data below:
[[{"id":1, "productId":1, "brand":"ASUS",...... }],
[{"id":2, "productId":2, "brand":"DELL",....... }]]
Maybe [[{...}], [{...}]] does not work ???
Maybe [{...}, {...}] works ???
How can I make my code works?
If I don't use array.push, then what else I can use?
Or, what other approach I can try?
Thank you very much in advance!
Cookies

If finalRes is an array and you want to push its elements to list_of_computers rather than pushing the entire array as a single element, spread it into the push operation:
this.list_of_computers.push(...finalRes);

